# Context error in RecyclerVIew Adapter onBIndVIewHolder using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-adapter, android-viewholder

Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type sort.media.sound.audio.workshoplecture2.Contacts
This is the error I get.

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


public class FindFriendActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolBar;
    private RecyclerView FindFriendsRecylerList;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_friend);

        UsersRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        FindFriendsRecylerList=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_recycler_lists);
        FindFriendsRecylerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        mToolBar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Find Friends");
    }

    @Override
    public  void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>
                ().setQuery(UsersRef,Contacts.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts,FindFriendsViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contacts model) {
                model=new Contacts();

                holder.userName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.userStatus.setText(model.getStatus());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.profileImage);




            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FindFriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout,viewGroup,false);
                FindFriendsViewHolder findFriendsViewHolder=new FindFriendsViewHolder(view);
                return findFriendsViewHolder;

            }
        };

        FindFriendsRecylerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    public static  class    FindFriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userName,userStatus;
        CircleImageView profileImage;


        public FindFriendsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            userName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_name);
            userStatus=itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_status);
            profileImage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        }
    }
}
```

My Contacts Class

```
package sort.media.sound.audio.workshoplecture2;

public class Contacts {

    String name;
    String image;
    String status;

    public Contacts()
    {

    }
    public Contacts(String name, String image, String status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI it's important to know how best to format code for display in Stack Overflow questions.  Please make a note of how I edited it.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database

Comment: ok im sending it.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo